# Combine functions for same collection

Tags: clojure

I just start learning `Clojure`, and I get used in other functional language create some pipelines with functions like

```
val result = filter(something)
             map(something)
             reduce(something)
         collection
```

I'm trying to achieve something like that with Clojure combining two `filter` functions

```
(defn filter-1 [array] (filter
                         (fn [word] (or (= word "politrons") (= word "hello"))) array))
(defn filter-2 [array] (filter
                         (fn [word] (= word "politrons")) array))

(def result (filter-1 ["hello" "politrons" "welcome" "to" "functional" "lisp" ""]))

(println "First:" result)

(println "Pipeline:" ((filter-2 result)))
```

But I'm unable to make it works.

Could you please can provide some advice or documentation of how to combine two `predicate` functions for a same `collection`?

Regards

Comment: Check out the threading macros:  https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two `filter-$` functions are fully fledged already (Note, that you
would gain more re-usability by making your predicates functions and not
the whole filtering with the predicate hidden).

So to make that work, you can go with the thread-last macro `->>`:

```
(->> array
     filter-1
     filter-2)
```

This is a rather general approach, you will see often in code
in the wild.  More general:

```
(->> xs
     (filter pred?)
     (map tf)
     (remove pred?))
```

The newer approach for this are
[transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers), where the
combination is done via `comp`.  And this would also be the way to
actually combine your whole transformation pipeline into a new function.

E.g.

```
(def my-xf
 (comp 
   (filter pred1)
   (filter pred2)))

(into [] my-xf xs)
```

Note the use of the single argument version on `filter`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me read that document and try this approach.

Answer (score 4):

there are some options to compose processing steps:

you can just pipeline filter calls like this:

```
   (->> data
        (filter #{"politrons" "hello"})
        (filter #{"politrons"}))
   ;;=> ("politrons")
```

notice these word sets to be used as filter functions (just a shortcut for those equality predicates of yours)

but i guess what you need to know, is the [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) concept, since it's usages include (but not limited to) this type of pipelining you need:

```
(eduction (filter #{"politrons" "hello"})
          (filter #{"hello"})
          data)
;;=> ("hello")
```

in case you just need filtering, you can also combine filter function with higher-level functions like `every-pred`:

```
(filter (every-pred #{"politrons" "hello"}
                    #(= "olleh" (clojure.string/reverse %)))
        data)
;;=> ("hello")
```

Comment: Ooo I I didn't know about `every-pred`, and it looks like `->>` and `eduction` are similar, except the input goes on the end.

Comment: @AaronBell The eduction still uses the power of transducers - so no
intermediate sequences.